# Install a package from Xenial 16.04

Tags: lubuntu

I need libSDL 2.0.4, but it is included only in upcoming Xenial 16.04. What safe wsy to install it could you recommend to me? I currently use lubuntu 15.04 and 15.10.
I see 2 alternatives: to build from sources and install to a separate dir, or to manually download xenial package (and it's dependencies) and use dpkg -i.
First way takes time, but second looks unsafe. Or maybe there is another solution?
Thanks.